# Handle Violation of PRIMARY KEY while insert in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I created a stored procedure (sp) which inserts rows into a table by a select statement.

It inserts all the value of attribute contained in all the tables of the database.

During execution of sp other attributes are added into tables, then sp is executed again.

The procedure should ignore the violation of primary key and add the new attributes added recently.

The procedure is not inserting any row when the primary key is violated.

Is this possible in sql server?

Comment: Any examples? A bit more clarity? The question is hard to understand in it's current form

Comment: Are you looking for a query like onduplicate key update of mysql?

Comment: Please post sample query.

Comment: Insertion on primary key violation?? do yo mean new row should have new value for `primary key` column on second insertion?

Comment: For example i have tow table named Hotel(HotelId, name ,adress) and manager(id,name); when i execute the procedure it looks into attribte of the tow table and insert into a table named dictionary 5 rows (each row has the name of attribute as primary key). Now when i add adress to the table hotel and age to manager, i want that when i execute the procedure it add this tow rows. The problem that my procedure iterate in all attribute name so it found someone which actualy exist and can't add anything

Comment: If performance is what has made you choose column `attribute` as primary key then based on your data you should create a `NON-Clustered` index on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Merge

```
-- MERGE statement with the join conditions specified correctly.
USE tempdb;
GO 
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE Target AS T
USING Source AS S ON (T.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID)  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND S.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%' 
THEN INSERT(EmployeeID, EmployeeName) VALUES(S.EmployeeID, S.EmployeeName)
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE SET T.EmployeeName = S.EmployeeName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND T.EmployeeName LIKE 'S%'
THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

For details refer [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Great idea, I can used  to know what actualy exsit and ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Inserting Same ID's into primary key column is not possible.

Instead alter your table to have identity column as primary key and rest all can be same to insert your data.